# Is it possible to create snake case `related_name` from class interpolation in Django related fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django allows us to use [`'%(class)s'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name) to automatically create related name from mixins. But when I have a `ClassName` I'd rather access it using `class_name`, not `classname`. I know it's only semantics but I was wondering if it's possible to adjust model field to make it snake case instead.

I was browsing through [django.db.models.fields](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/models/fields) but I can't find where the class interpolation is happening.

Example code

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    pass


class UserRelatedMixin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        to=User,
        parent_link=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='%(class)s',
        related_query_name="%(class)s",
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class HomeAddress(UserRelatedMixin):
    pass


user = User.objects.first()
```

What I have

```
user.homeaddress
```

What I want instead

```
user.home_address
```

Right now I'm using a `@property` but it won't allow ORM queries so it's a partial solution.

Comment: Looked at the code a bit and found that [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e412b288455dd3ea6f1d65c8ec5d01751e489976/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L289) is where the related_name is formatted to include the class name. Don't know how to change this without actually building custom fields for that. Does setting `__name__ = 'Home_Address'` in the HomeAddress class work? If it does would be an ugly hack though.

Comment: Nope, it does not work :) . I think property method is the only way to achive this even if it is a partial solution.

Comment: Only option is to inherit and override The fields `contribute_to_class` then.

Comment: Thanks for looking so deep. I've found this piece of code as well but wasn't sure that's the place. If so, I'd rather not touch it.