# Django Setting for Default Related Name Pattern

Tags: python, django

The [Django documentation: Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#:%7E:text=the%20default%20reverse%20name%20will%20be%20the%20name%20of%20the%20child%20class) page mentions that the default `related_name` for foreign keys uses the pattern `f"{ModelClass.__name__.lower()}_set"` (or `childb_set` in the specific example).

Is there a way to configure Django to convert `CapWords` to `cap_words` (instead of `capwords`) when creating these default `related_name`s?

For example, take the following models:

```py
from django.db import models

class BlogChannel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ArticleAuthor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TextEntry(models.Model):
    blog_channel = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    article_authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    number_of_comments = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

Accessing `BlogChannel` records through `TextEntry` is intuitive:

```py
>>> text_entry = TextEntry.objects.first()
>>> blog_channel = text_entry.blog_channel
```

But the reverse is not:

```py
>>> blog_channel.text_entry_set    # should be `blog_channel.textentry_set`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-0402bfca7d1f> in <module>
----> 1 blog_channel.text_entry_set

AttributeError: 'BlogChannel' object has no attribute 'text_entry_set'
```

Rather than modifying every foreign key field of every model to specify a `related_name` that uses underscores, I'm curious if there is a setting or something to effect this style change.

Comment: Not exactly possible unless you go and create your own custom relation fields, which honestly would be more work to maintain the just setting the `related_name` yourself. Looking at the code [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8a7ac78b706797a03d26b88eddb9d1067ed35b66/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py#L180-L195) is where the accessor name is made. Also here is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66169631/is-it-possible-to-create-snake-case-related-name-from-class-interpolation-in-d) (again no answer, or similar need to override fields, etc.)

Comment: Or you can try dabbling in metaclasses and [set the `__name__` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781234/setting-a-class-name-declaratively) of the class such that it in lowercase would end up being in snake case. Although I don't know if that would be recommended.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, you are right. As you saw in '12 the way is to override `contribute_to_class`

Comment: Ah thanks for the help! Yeah I agree; I think this is one of the instances where it makes more sense to ignore PEP-8 for ORM relationships than to try to force it